# tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: causing Assertion failure

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a tableView showing an `NSMutableArray` of an object and I am currently trying to implement the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method. If I comment out the line `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` everything works just fine, outside of updating the UI.

This is my implementation of the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.modelClass removeObjectAtRow:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2280.1/UITableView.m:1060
```

Other questions have had answers suggesting that I need to replace the `@[indexPath]` with `[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]`, and that just comes up with the same error.

Comment: Did my solution work for you???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes because `UITableView` enters the datasource method `numberOfRowsInSection` again, after the deletion of rows. Make sure that it returns correct number of rows that is your `self.modelClass.count` in  `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: the numberOfRowsInSection is what the problem was, but it works just fine with `@[indexPath]` in it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tarheel That is quite weird, if i use `@[indexPath]` i get an error saying `unexpected @ in program` hmmm, glad to help.

Comment: @iNoob - the OP is using Xcode 4.5 where objc supports new literals for arrays and for dictionaries (@[] and @{} respectively).

Answer (score 3):

Might be the problem is in method `numberOfRowsInSection` So, to leave troubles you should:

In function `commitEditingStyle` delete data from your array, database etc.
Decrement your current row count.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

And your problem will be solved!!!